# How to mock DynamoDB batch save?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, amazon-dynamodb

I wrote the dynamoDB code which stores list of items.

```
mapper.batchSave(trafficSensorReadings)
```

This will return.

```
List<FailedBatch>
```

I want to mock the mapper.batchSave and then return one failed job. How can I achieve it? I am using mockito and Junit.

I wrote something like this. But not useful.

```
        when(dynamoDBMapper.batchSave(eq(List.class))).thenReturn(mock(List.class));
```

Answer (score 2):

A complete example follows

```
@Test
public void test() {
    FailedBatch failedBatch = mock(FailedBatch.class);
    List<FailedBatch> failedBatchList = new ArrayList<>();
    failedBatchList.add(failedBatch);
    DynamoDBMapper dynamoDBMapperMock = mock(DynamoDBMapper.class);
    when(dynamoDBMapperMock.batchSave(any(List.class))).thenReturn(failedBatchList);

    tested.testedMethodCall();

    verify(dynamoDBMapperMock).batchSave(any(List.class));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, I think you might want to use Mockito.any() instead of Mockito.eq().

Second, I don't see why you would want to mock the list. You can just create one and return it

```
// GIVEN
FailedBatch batch1 = /**/;
FailedBatch batch2 = /**/;
List<FailedBatch> failedBatchList = Lists.newArrayList(batch1, batch2);

// WHEN
when(dynamoDBMapper.batchSave(any(List.class))).thenReturn(failedBatchList);

Object someResult = yourFunctionTestCall();

// THEN
verify(someResult)...
```