# How to mock failed DynamoDB batchSave()?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, mockito

I am trying to mock a failed DynamoDB mapper.batchSave() using mockito.

Following this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38129616/how-to-mock-dynamodb-batch-save), I can mock a successful `.batchSave()`

```java
List<DynamoDBMapper.FailedBatch> emptyFailedBatches = new ArrayList<>. ();
when(mapper.batchSave((Iterable<? extends Object>) any())).thenReturn(emptyFailedBatches);
```

But instead of having an `emptyFailedBatches`, I want to return a list of failedBatches that include my objects, which failed to save.

Comment: What problem exactly are you having doing this?